# Suggest tag migration identity -> identity-column

Tags: feature-request, tagging, tag-synonyms

`identity` is just too vague to be useful as a tag. It refers to *Identity Columns*, or should. So I think we should migrate it to `identity-column` (which the SQL spec uses to refer to them).

And also merge `generated-as-identity` with the new tag (or the old tag) since it has only 2 questions and has no place.

Comment: 'Tis also a function -- [IDENTITY (Function)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/identity-function-transact-sql) -- though its purpose is for creating an identity column. Still, FYI :-)

Answer (score 4):

Some might prefer the master tag to be named [identity-property](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identity-property) (as in SQL Standard feature F384 "Drop identity property clause") with the following synonyms:

- [identity-column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identity-column)
- [generated-as-identity](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/generated-as-identity)
- [identity](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identity)

...so I am providing this as an answer option.

For example, in SQL Server *identity* is referred to as a [property of a column](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property).

Comment: Is it safe to assume that questions related to the [IDENTITY (Function)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/identity-function-transact-sql) would naturally use the **identity** tag?

Comment: Never assume anything :) But, yes, I would think so.

Comment: I think that's a good idea, didn't realize the spec called it `identity property`. That works for me